# Is there a query to toggle the general_log global setting on/off?

Tags: mysql, global-variables, global, mariadb

Can I simply toggle a (GLOBAL) variable's state with a query? That is, if it's `'ON'` make it `'OFF'` and if it's `'OFF'` make it `'ON'`.

I tried this:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = IF(general_log = 'ON', 'OFF', 'ON')
```

but that produces an error.

Comment: The triple backtick syntax doesn't work in StackOverflow's markdown (I think that's a GitHub-only addition).

Comment: `@@general_log` would let you access the variable within a query, but `select @@general_log` comes back as a bit, e.g. 0/1, not on/off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
set global general_log = if (@@general_log, 'OFF', 'ON')
```

Note that `@@general_log` is either `0` or `1` (it's a `bit` type) and in MySQL these values are `false` and `true` respectively.